# Copy RTF/HTML markup with Zeroclipboard

Tags: javascript, copy, rtf, zeroclipboard

I am trying to copy the contents of a div using Zeroclipboard.  I have successfully implemented the copying of plain text on my site [here](http://www.ultrasoundoftheweek.com/citation/), but I have a link embedded in the div that I'd like be copied as well.  I did find [this Github discussion](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/issues/143) on implementation of this, but couldn't find an example of the code to modify.

Here is my current Zeroclipboard JS:

```
ZeroClipboard.config( { moviePath: '/scripts/ZeroClipboard.swf' } );

var client = new ZeroClipboard( $("#copy-button") );

client.on( 'load', function(client) {

  client.on( 'datarequested', function(client) {
    var text = $('#result').text();
    client.setText(text);
  });

  // callback triggered on successful copying
  client.on( 'complete', function(client, args) {
    console.log("Text copied to clipboard: \n" + args.text );
  });
});

// In case of error - such as Flash not being available
client.on( 'wrongflash noflash', function() {
  ZeroClipboard.destroy();
} );
```

Comment: Try
    var innerHTML = $('#result').innerHTML();
    client.setText(innerHTML);

Comment: I tried this suggestion and still can't get it working.